# Testing Availability of Http service 'http://localhost:21012/'

Tags: exception, delphi, post, indy

Some XmlRpc server may be installed by a web application and I am searching to test avaiability of corresponding service.

Windows 10, Delphi 11, Indy 10.6

```
Var
  WplHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  RequestBody: TStringStream;
  XmlReqst:string ;
begin
 //The XML-RPC endpoint for Web Profile requests is at the root of that server,
 // so that web clients can access it by POSTing to the URL “http://localhost:21012/”.
   result:=false;
   try
        XmlReqst:=C_xmlFrame;    // dummy request pour test
        RequestBody := TStringStream.create(XmlReqst);         //ok
        wplHTTP:=TidHTTP.Create;
        wplhTTP.HTTPOptions := wplHTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException]+[hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
        wplHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/xml';
        wplHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/xml';
            try
              responseBody := wplHTTP.Post('http://localhost:21012/', RequestBody);
            except
              on E:EIdHTTPProtocolException do
              begin
                WriteLn(E.Message);
                WriteLn(E.ErrorMessage);
                result := false;
              end;
            end;
            Response := responseBody;
            if response <> ''  then   result :=  true;
          finally
            requestbody.Free;
            wplHTTP.Destroy;
       end;
```

I choose to test posting a sample request but it seems that i have no way to test the return `{AERR=10061}` in case of absence [working fine if service is started].

IdStack module appears with this line:

```
raise EIdSocketError.CreateError(AErr, WSTranslateSocketErrorMsg(AErr));
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly asking `TIdHTTP` to NOT raise `EIdHTTPProtocolException` (which is fine), but you are trying to catch ONLY it (why?), and then you wonder why you are getting other exceptions that you are NOT catching?

The line of code you quoted literally tells you the type of exception that is being raised (`EIdSocketError`), so simply catch that type of exception in your `except` block *instead of* `EIdHTTPProtocolException`, eg:

```
try
  ...
except
  on E: EIdSocketError do
  begin
    WriteLn(E.Message);
    WriteLn('Error Code: ' + IntToStr(E.LastError));
    Result := false;
  end;
end;
```

Though, I would suggest restructuring your code a little more like this instead:

```
var
  WplHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  RequestBody: TStringStream;
  XmlReqst: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  XmlReqst := C_xmlFrame;
  RequestBody := TStringStream.Create(XmlReqst);
  try
    wplHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      wplhTTP.HTTPOptions := wplHTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
      wplHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/xml';
      wplHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/xml';
      try
        Response := wplHTTP.Post('http://localhost:21012/', RequestBody);
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          WriteLn(E.Message);
          if E is EIdSocketError then
            WriteLn('Error Code: ' + IntToStr(EIdSocketError(E).LastError));
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
      Result := Response <> '';
    finally
      wplHTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    RequestBody.Free;
  end;
end;
```